# Urban Airship autobadge +1 never increments. Always sets to 1

Tags: push-notification, urbanairship.com

I'm trying to use the [autobadge](http://docs.urbanairship.com/integration.html#autobadge-examples) functionality with Urban Airship to increment the badge number on an iOS app.

I send "badge":"+1" but sets the badge=1 instead of incrementing it.

Here's the payload

```
{"audience":{"alias":"C045AFYMPAM"},"notification":{"ios":{"badge":"+1","alert":"Nick Gonzalez: Test"}},"device_types":["ios"],"options":{"expiry":1800}}}
```

The alert shows up, and the badge shows up, but it always shows up as 1 and never increments.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue/solution and it's really straightforward but I'll answer it here nonetheless in the case that it's helpful for someone else.

When converting the payload to json it was converting the string "+1" to integer 1 which was keeping it from incrementing and was setting the badge to 1. Make sure your encoding function isn't converting "+1" to 1.